# unable to remove an object from localStorage using its id

Tags: javascript

```
function removeLocalStorageHelper(item, pizzaId) {
  console.log(item.productID);
  console.log(pizzaId);
  if (item.productID == pizzaId) {
    console.log("Working fine");
    localStorage.removeItem(item);
    console.log(localStorage);
  }
}
function removeFromLocalStorage(pizzaId) {
  var locStore = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("selectedProduct"));
  var cartRowContents = locStore.map((item) =>
    removeLocalStorageHelper(item, pizzaId)
  );
}
```

Whenever the user clicks on "Remove" button, `removeFromLocalStorage()` function is called which receives a number type variable `pizzaId`. Now, this `pizzaId` is stored in the localStorage and I want to remove the object associated with this `pizzaId` from my localStorage.

#### CONSOLE OUTPUT

[image]

[image]
Please help me to remove an object from localStorage using `productID`.

Comment: You need to provide a key to delete a specific item from local storage.

Comment: `item` in the mapper function is not a key, it's a live object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't directly remove an item from the stored array. For that you need to remove the intended element from array and insert again to localStorage like below. Otherwise it'll remove complete list from localStorage.

Note: You need to do the same wile adding new item to the localStorage.

```js
function removeFromLocalStorage(pizzaId) {
  var locStore = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("selectedProduct"));
  var cartRowContents = locStore.filter((item) => item.productID !== pizzaId);
  localStorage.setItem("selectedProduct", JSON.stringify(cartRowContents))
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. We need to just use localStorage.setItem("selectedProduct", JSON.stringify(cartRowContents));

Answer (score 2):

As I reivew your code, I see that you are retrieving the item from localStorage like this `localStorage.getItem("selectedProduct")` The question here is do you want to remove the entire `locStore` or just a part of it. Maybe `locStore` is a complex collection (array) from multiple products and not a single entity as this code hints

```
var cartRowContents = locStore.map((item) =>
   removeLocalStorageHelper(item, pizzaId));
```

If this is the case you need to do something like this

```
var locStore = locStore.filter(function(item, index){ 
    return item.productID != pizzaId;
});
```

Now you have a `locStore` collection without the item you want to remove and you have to save it back to localStorage like this

```
localStorage.setItem('selectedProduct', JSON.stringify(locStore));
```

Essentially you are overriding the old `selectedProduct` value in `localStorage` with a new one that does not contain the removed product.

If for some reason `locStore` is just a simple JSON object that you want to remove you can do this to delete it from `localStorage`

```
localStorage.removeItem('selectedProduct')
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you just need to remove the selectedProduct, you can do it like this:

```
localStorage.removeItem("selectedProduct");
```

Comment: There's a key 'productId' inside each object in selectedProduct. I want to delete that object where productId == pizzaId

Comment: Okay, now I see. The answer by Anton Kovachev should answer your question.